# Complement of a number

Tags: math

I read on wikipedia :
"In general, for a radix r's complement encoding, with r the base (radix) of the number system, an integer part of m digits and fractional part of n digits, then the r's complement of a number 0 ≤ N < r^(m−1)−r^(−n) is determined by the formula:

N** = (r^m − N) mod (r^m) "

I don't understand that does the number of digits i.e. m depend on the radix r ?
For ex : If I want to find 100's complement of 97 then is m=2 or m=1 ?
For m=2, I get the answer as 9903
For m=1, I get the answer as 03
So should I take m=2 or m=1 ?

Comment: can you post the address of the Wikipedia article you're referring to?  I'm interesting in seeing the reading.  Thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement#Complement_of_a_positive_number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wikipedia article on the [method of complements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_complements) can probably give a much better explanation than I can, but I will try nonetheless.

The number of digits does not necessarily depend on the radix, rather the context in which it is used. In other words, 5 does not have a complement in base-2 (i.e. binary), but it *does* have a complement in an *eight-digit* base-2 number -- 251. This means that in two's complement, `-5` can be represented as `0b11111011`.

Likewise, 97 does not have a complement in base-100. It *does* have a complement in a one-digit integer, a two-digit integer or an n-digit integer base-100 number.

You may choose to develop an arithmetic machine that works with 100's complement numbers. If you use one-digit integers, you could represent `-3` by your 97th numeral. If you preferred two-digit integers, `-3` would be represented by your 99th numeral followed by your 97th numeral.

---

This is a difficult concept at first, doubly so in a numeral system that hasn't been developed -- I've yet to see base-100. :-) Try flexing your method of complements muscle in smaller bases first, hexadecimal is a good start.

16's complement of 7 in a single-digit hexadecimal number is 9. In a two-digit number, it is F9. In a three-digit number, it is FF9. Hence